# When I try to scale the faces on my mesh by transforming multiple components individually, it doesn't work like I want to

Tags: pivot, axis, maya, modeling

When I try to scale Y axis to the faces on my mesh by transforming multiple components individually ( which I set the axis orientation to Component). They didn't work like I expect.
[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vDn1.png)
[After scaling the Y axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLIvp.png)

Both of the individual face loops should be scaled down in the Y axis. I tried to change the Axis Orientation but it doens't help.